# Specify --reporter and --env in command line start of Cypress test runner

Tags: npm, command-line, command-line-arguments, cypress

I've looked all over the place to find information on this, but no luck.

Here is my situation:

I would like to be able to specify a config file to point to for running my tests, and also specify the reporter that I would like to use for said tests.

I am running my tests in Team City, which has native 'reporter' support in cypress.
In the past, prior to my environment loading needs, I supplied the following command line to run my tests and specify the reporter:

```
npm run cypress run --reporter teamcity
```

However, I now need to specify the environment / config to point to, which I do like so:

```
cypress run --env configFile=[env]
```

I would like to be able to specify both in the command line so that I can point to the environment and also specify the reporter. I have tried the following, with no success:

```
npm run cypress open --env configFile=[env] --reporter teamcity
npm run cypress open --env configFile=[env] || --reporter teamcity
npm run cypress open --env configFile=[env] / --reporter teamcity
npm run cypress open --env configFile=[env] && --reporter teamcity
```

I have been unable to find any documentation around this, unfortunately.
Is there a way to both specify the environment and the reporter after calling npm cypress run?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this was user error. I was trying to specify reporter on a cypress 'open' command, where it is not supported. The reporter option is only supported on the run command, which does not require additional syntax to execute, even with the configFile specification.